# Access Denied on use of AppPrincipalManager

Tags: 2013, permissions, sharepoint-addin, client-object-model, app

We are getting the following error

```
Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.
```

when executing the following code

```
AppPrincipalManager ap = AppPrincipalManager.GetManager(web.Context, web);
web.Context.ExecuteQuery();
```

I get it with every account: my account (site collection admin), system account, ...
It just doesn't work.

We need it because we want to add apps on a site by CSOM. That works, but the app permissions are not set. So we are trying to set them by the AppPrincipalManager. But then, we get an access denied error.

Comment: Also with app only policy it fails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our company contacted Microsoft, and this is by design.
For security reasons you cannot set the permissions of an app by client side code